# How to refresh the Google Plus bearer token when using the AWS JavaScript SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, aws-sdk

I am trying to use the AWS "SDK for the browser" to perform direct calls to some AWS services, and perform user authentication using Google Plus.

The initial authentication works correctly, and after I set the bearer token I receive from Google Plus inside AWS, I can perform direct S3 calls from within the browser. My issue comes with long user sessions, for which the initial bearer token expires and my calls to S3 start throwing errors (the error being that I am using an expired access token).

I suspect that AWS is not calling the Google Plus endpoint for a refresh token, and it still uses the initial one I set.

So is there a way to force the Google API to give me a completly new bearer token which I can set in AWS? If I call:

```
var clientId = "<my client id>",
    scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email";

gapi.auth.authorize({
    client_id: clientId,
    scope: scope,
    immediate: true
}, function(r) { console.log(r.id_token) });
```

I always get the same bearer token, even if it expired. But if I refresh the page, then I do indeed get a completly new one. So is there a way to force the GAPI to give me a new bearer token which I can set in AWS. Or is there a method on the AWS SDK which I need to call to ensure that it uses a refresh token?

**Update:** If I call `auth.signIn` instead of `auth.authorize` like so:

```
gapi.auth.signIn({
    clientid: clientId,
    scope: scope,
    cookiepolicy : 'single_host_origin',
    response_type: 'id_token token gsession',
    callback: loginToGoogle,
    immediate: true
})
```

Then I get a new `id_token`, but it shows the annoying sign-in pop-up for a few milliseconds before it closes itself. Is there any other way of getting a new bearer token on the client without showing the pop-up window?

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that gapi.auth.authorize doesn't work correctly in this case.
Could you add

`cookiepolicy : 'single_host_origin',
 response_type: 'id_token token gsession',`

to the gapi.auth.authorize params?

At what point are you starting to get errors? Is it when token expires (you can determine that by checking .expires_at property in the response)? Are you getting the same access_token  when token is expired?

Offline access flow is an alternative: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer